# How to show a message " Registered Successfully"

Tags: android, messagebox

I m showing a dialog box for 5000ms now I want to show a message "Registered successfully" after  that dialog box disappears. How can I do this?

Thanks$Regards.

Here is the code

```
   Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regsubmitbtn);

    signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    register();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        removeDialog(0);
//   I want to show the dialog box like registered successfully after removing this dialog//
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
       @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0: {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Registering...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        return dialog;
    }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a Dialogbox, you can use a Toast object.  This can be configured to disappear after a certain time.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: @C Nick, Thanks but I want Toast object to appear after 5000ms how to do this?

Comment: @Raj, your question said that after 5s the dialog box disappears - whatever trigger you use to dismiss the dialog, you can use to display the Toast also. If you are not dismissing the dialog in your code, then you should clarify your question.

Comment: @RivieraKid , Thank u for ur valuable suggestion, what u said is correct I want to display a toast only,I am new to android and could u help with the code snippet

Comment: @Mutmatt has got there already, but be aware, you can currently only choose LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG for the duration of how long it will be displayed for.

Answer (score 1):

`Toast.makeText(myclass.this, "The text i want to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity{

    Button btn = null;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    int counter = 0;
    Thread t =null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myxml);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn001);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          tv.setHint(tv.getHint());
//          while(counter<2){

            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
//                  register();
                    try {
//                        while(counter<2){
                        updateGallery(0);
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        updateGallery(2);
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                        updateGallery(1);


//                        }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
                }
            };
            t.start();

            }
//          tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkBlue));
//      }
    });



//  tv.setFreezesText(true);
}




@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
 switch (id) {
  case 0: {

      ++counter;
  dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

  dialog.setMessage("Registering...");

  dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
  dialog.setCancelable(true);

}

}
 return dialog;
}

public void updateGallery(int actionsToBePerformedOnScreen) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = actionsToBePerformedOnScreen;
    galleryListHandler.sendMessage(msg);

}

public Handler galleryListHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 0:

            showDialog(0);

            break;

        case 1:
            // clear all images in the list

            removeDialog(0);

            break;
        case 2:
            dialog.setMessage("Registered successfully");
            break;

        }

    };
};
}
```

Comment: @Raj in your question you have asked about dialog box